# Pausing for a dynamic image to load / display with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing up a image carousel which checks a directory for newly uploaded images (based on sequential file names) and adds them to the carousel.

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({

// Checks to see if file exists
url : imageUrl,
success : function (xhr, d, e) {

// Adds image found at imageUrl to the carousel
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("addContent", imageData);

// Increments imageUrl from /images/image01.jpg to images/image02.jpg etc
imageListener();
},

error : function (xhr, d, e) {
if (xhr.status == 404) {
}
}
});
}, 5000);
```

This all works great for images already uploaded, but what's happening is I think as I upload a new image, it returns success on the existence of the image, and tries to add it to the carousel before it's finished uploading, and I end up with images that aren't displayed properly / appear offline. I figure I need some way of halting things until the upload and adding to the carousel are complete. It's probably very simple but I'm new and have tried lots of things but no success. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Use the `.load()` event on image elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload images to a temp folder then when upload is completed move it to the actual folder

Comment: Would never have thought of this! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes alternative routes are shorter and easier that direct routes :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using XHR to determine that the file exists, why not just create a new Image and set its src to the URL and wait to see whether you get a load or an error event?

Comment: Did this and whilst it didn't quite fix this problem (ended up using Ergec's idea), it fixed another one I was having so thank you!